# how can i map through this array object properly in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

```
const demo = [
  {
    a: "message",
    b: "another message",
    c: [{ ab: "inner message", cd: "another inner message" }, { ab: "inner message" ,cd: "another inner message" }],
  },
];

const maping = demo.map((i) => {
  return i.c.map((j)=>{return j.ab});
});
console.log(maping);
```

All I want to get an array object like this:

```
[ {ab: "inner message"},{ab: "inner message" } ],
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
[ [ {ab: "inner message"},{ab: "inner message" } ] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some way to get the structure you want:

```js
const demo = [
  {
    a: "message",
    b: "another message",
    c: [{ ab: "inner message", cd: "another inner message" }, { ab: "inner message" ,cd: "another inner message" }],
  },
];

const mapping1 = demo.map(i => {
  return i.c.map(j => ({ab: j.ab}));
}).flat();
console.log("mapping1", mapping1);

const mapping2 = demo.reduce((r, i) => {
  return r.concat(i.c.map(j => ({ab: j.ab})))
}, []);
console.log("mapping2", mapping2);
```

ref:

- [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: we can get by using `flatMap()`  here `method const maping = demo.map((i) => {
  return i.c.map((j)=>{return j.ab});
}).flatMap((e)=> e)`